# How to find data copies of a given file in Btrfs filesystem?

Tags: btrfs, deduplication

I have deduplicated my Btrfs filesystem with bedup, so now all duplicate files (above a certain size) are "reflink" copies.

Is there any way to see, given a filename, what other files are the same reflinks?

Comment: If there's no btrfs native way, you could always run `filefrag -v` on all the files and find common ranges.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that doesn't work. two unrelated files with nothing in common show the same output

Comment: @Hilikus, you may need to issue a `sync` especially if the flags show _unknown_loc_ or _delalloc_

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas https://gist.github.com/theHilikus/5fd0e38fd72fbcc97ae45ced703b0b47
as you see, two different files with different content and size give the same offsets

Comment: @Hilikus, those have the _inline_ flag, so have no data/extent associated (data stored with metadata) so can't possibly be reflinked.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas please see the updated gist. i created a reflink with `cp --reflink=always` and the flag is still *inline* but the files are (i have to assume cp works, but i can't prove it) reflinked. am I missing something else?

Comment: ok, i think I got it. I tried with a bigger file that's not *inlined* and Stephane's method does seem to work. I guess that `cp --reflink=always` doesn't always create a reflink. If the file is small enough that its data can be stored with the metadata (inline) then --reflink=always doesn't to any reflinking

Comment: @Hilikus, yes in that case, there's nothing to reflink (same as for empty files, or short symlinks, there's no data block). To sum up, instead of comparing `filefrag -v`, compare `filefrag -v | grep -ve inline -e unknown_loc -e delalloc` as those can't be reflinked. You'll notice another clue in that the "physical offset" is always 0 for those (even though of course they're not all located at the start of the block device)

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of having a Copy-On-Write (CoW) filesystem like btrfs is that the content of multiple versions of a file can be efficiently shared. So you might see a file as a collection of ranges with contents, where the content might or might not be shared by other files. Or by other versions of the file. The implementation is more like a tree of extends, where extends may be shared.

The same mechanism which works during writing a change to a file (and therefore producing a new version of that file) is being used to do the deduplification. The implementation is described on https://github.com/g2p/bedup :

> Deduplication is implemented using a Btrfs feature that allows for cloning data from one file to the other. The cloned ranges become shared on disk, saving space.

The implementation in the kernel is (for example) at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/btrfs/ioctl.c#L2843 ; the comment makes it clear that it is not about 'reflinking' the file, but about ranges:

```
2843 /**
2844  * btrfs_clone() - clone a range from inode file to another
2845  *
2846  * @src: Inode to clone from
2847  * @inode: Inode to clone to
2848  * @off: Offset within source to start clone from
2849  * @olen: Original length, passed by user, of range to clone
2850  * @olen_aligned: Block-aligned value of olen, extent_same uses
2851  *               identical values here
2852  * @destoff: Offset within @inode to start clone
2853  */
```

So it is not the file which is reflinked, its the range which is shared. A new file could also have been constructed by sharing range with multiple files. Or being shared across volumes. Or (not sure if this is currently supported) even having the same range multiple times in the same file ;)

Therefore, no high-level tool exists to find files which share the whole file  since this is a derived concept. Of course it would be possible to write support for it, but that's not the case as far as I know...

Answer (score 2):

I have just released a program called [`fienode`](https://github.com/pwaller/fienode) (← link) which computes a SHA1 hash of the physical extents of a file. Identical CoW copies have the same hash.

In principle, you can run this across all files on the filesystem and then look for identical hashes.

There is also a more detailed answer here, explaining why this is necessary.

- [How to verify a file copy is reflink/CoW?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277033/26224)

Note however, that BTRFS is at liberty to change the physical extents. I've observed a large reflinked file changes its physical extents without provocation, making the `fienode` output different, even though the majority of the physical extents were still shared.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679796/42620