# List reflink filenames to a file on btrfs

Tags: btrfs

Given a path/filename on a btrfs filesystem, how can you see the other reflinked path/filenames to the same file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find data copies of a given file in Btrfs filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128055/how-to-find-data-copies-of-a-given-file-in-btrfs-filesystem)