# Detect btrfs reflinked files

Tags: btrfs, reflink

It's clear, with `cp --reflink foo bar` I can copy a file on btrfs without wasting space. But how can I detect that the two files (foo and bar here) are using the same "space unit"?

If they were hardlinks, I would use `[ foo -ef bar ]` for comparing or `stat -c%i foo` to get a unique id (inode in this case).

Are there similar commands for btrfs reflinked files?

I want to apply this on a 300G volume which is virtually 6T in size due to deduplication, so I want to avoid checksumming...

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225766/list-reflink-filenames-to-a-file-on-btrfs?rq=1, but it's not exactly the same question

Comment: I would suggest looking at how https://github.com/markfasheh/duperemove detects extents that are already shared.  AFAIK, that's about the only way to do it reliably, though I unfortunately couldn't explain it to you because I don't fully understand it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is probably the best so far: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277043/55508, by @pwaller

> [Further to my previous
>   answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277033/26224), I have just
>   released [`fienode`](https://github.com/pwaller/fienode) which
>   computes a SHA1 hash of the physical extents of the file and can be
>   used to find some (identical) reflink copies. Beware though, there are
>   caveats (see [the
>   documentation](https://github.com/pwaller/fienode/blob/master/README.md)).
>   BTRFS decided to change some, but not all, of the physical extents of
>   a refink copy I made without provocation or warning, causing the value
>   to change.

Comment: The tools seems to detect files as similar which don't even have the same size. Now checking if this is only for <1 block files and why

Comment: https://github.com/pwaller/sharedextents/ by the same author is exactly what I was looking for.