# How to find out if a file on btrfs is copy-on-write?

Tags: linux, btrfs, coreutils

I know that `cp` has a `--reflink` option to control full copies vs. copy-on-write "copies".

On btrfs, can I use `ls` (or some other command) to find out whether a file shares (in a copy-on-write senses) some storage with another file?

EDIT: @StéphaneChazelas points me to `filefrag`, but that fails for me:

```
root@void:/tmp/mount# mount | tail -1
/tmp/back on /tmp/mount type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache)
root@void:/tmp/mount# df -h | tail -1
/dev/loop0       32M   13M   20M  38% /tmp/mount
root@void:/tmp/mount# ls -lh
total 8.0M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.0M Jan 19 08:43 one
root@void:/tmp/mount# cp --reflink=always one two
root@void:/tmp/mount# sync
root@void:/tmp/mount# ls -lh
total 16M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.0M Jan 19 08:43 one
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.0M Jan 19 08:45 two
root@void:/tmp/mount# df -h | tail -1
/dev/loop0       32M   13M   20M  38% /tmp/mount
root@void:/tmp/mount# filefrag -kvx one 
Filesystem type is: 9123683e
File size of one is 8388608 (8192 blocks of 1024 bytes)
FIEMAP failed with unknown flags 2
one: FIBMAP unsupported
root@void:/tmp/mount# uname -a
Linux void 4.1.7+ #817 PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:25:36 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: With `filefrag -v`, you can check whether two files have data in common.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Fails for me, see my edit.

Answer (score 7):

**Update (Jan-2021):** see comment by @bitinerant: ***"btrfs-debug-tree is now obsolete; use btrfs inspect-internal dump-tree"***

---

I don't know how to find it via the `ls` command. But if you really want it, you can use the **btrfs-progs/btrfs-debug-tree**.

With *reflink=always*, the files will share a common data block. This common data block (aka extents) has refs more than 1.

1. First you need to find the objectid for the files one and two

   ```
    #./btrfs-debug-tree  /dev/xvdc
    (Check under FS_TREE)
      <snip>
        item 8 key (256 DIR_INDEX 4) itemoff 15842 itemsize 33
            location key (259 INODE_ITEM 0) type FILE
            namelen 3 datalen 0 name: one
        item 9 key (256 DIR_INDEX 5) itemoff 15809 itemsize 33
            location key (260 INODE_ITEM 0) type FILE
            namelen 3 datalen 0 name: two
      </snip>
   ```

From above we can see its *259(one)* and *260(two)*.

2. Now find its refs. from extent tree. Below command will find the data block shared between two files.

   ```
    # ./btrfs-debug-tree  /dev/xvdc | grep -A2 "refs 2"
            extent refs 2 gen 9 flags DATA
            extent data backref root 5 objectid 260 offset 0 count 1
            extent data backref root 5 objectid 259 offset 0 count 1
   ```

Bonus: Create another reference:

```
# cp --reflink=always one three
```

verify the refcount is incremented by 1.

```
# ./btrfs-debug-tree   /dev/xvdc | grep -A3 "refs 3"
        extent refs 3 gen 9 flags DATA
        extent data backref root 5 objectid 260 offset 0 count 1
        extent data backref root 5 objectid 261 offset 0 count 1
        extent data backref root 5 objectid 259 offset 0 count 1
```

Here the data block is shared between three files which are pointed to by objectid *259,260,261*.

Comment: Thanks, good to know about `btrfs-debug-tree`.

Comment: `btrfs-debug-tree` is now obsolete; use `btrfs inspect-internal dump-tree`

Comment: @bitinerant Can you update the answer?

Comment: @endolith - sorry, but no. That's more than a simple edit, and I'm not the author.

Comment: @bitinerant That's exactly why editing was implemented

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
$ btrfs filesystem du .
       Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
    1.11GiB     1.11GiB           -  ./file1
    1.12GiB     1.12GiB           -  ./file2
    1.31GiB       0.00B           -  ./file3
    3.54GiB     2.23GiB     1.31GiB  .
```

In this example, 'file3' is a reflink copy as it is not consuming any Exclusive space.

Comment: that's doesn't seem to work when other snapshots exists, e.g. for backup purposes.

Answer (score 2):

@pwaller's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277044/42620) shows that a listing of the data extents of each file can be compared to see if two files share identical extents.  `filefrag` from the `e2fsprogs` package can (almost) do this.
`filefrag -v FILE1 FILE2` will show if FILE1 and FILE2 have the same extents, in which case they are reflinks of each other.

Doing this programatically in a script is harder because `filefrag` outputs the filename.  To do this, I have a patched copy of `filefrag` which makes two changes:

1. Output the device ID
2. Do not output the filename if only one filename is specified

With these changes, the outputs from two calls to `filefrag` can be compared.  If identical, then the two files are reflinks of each other.

One final caveat:  If the output from `filefrag` matches the regex `inline|unknown_loc|delalloc`, then the file cannot be reflinked since it has no data block.  To handle that case, I wrap my patched `filefrag` with a check for that pattern and append the filename itself to the output if I find it (to make the output unique per filename, so that it will not match the output for a different filename).  See @StéphaneChazelas's comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128055/42620) for more details.

I submitted a pull request (https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/pull/87) and an issue (https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/issues/88) for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have just released a program called [`fienode`](https://github.com/pwaller/fienode) (← link) which computes a SHA1 hash of the physical extents of a file. Identical CoW copies have the same hash.

There is also a more detailed answer here, explaining why this is necessary.

- [How to verify a file copy is reflink/CoW?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277033/26224)

Note however, that BTRFS is at liberty to change the physical extents. I've observed a large reflinked file changes its physical extents without provocation, making the `fienode` output different, even though the majority of the physical extents were still shared.

Comment: would https://github.com/pwaller/sharedextents/ be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

On `xfs` at least if the files have not been altered then `filefrag` sets a `shared` flag.

For example:

```
 >filefrag -e foobar
 Filesystem type is: 58465342
 File size of filesystems.docker is 1344 (1 block of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
 0:        0..       0:  348117738.. 348117738:      1:             last,eof
 foo: 1 extent found

 >cp --reflink=auto foo bar
 >filefrag -e foo
 Filesystem type is: 58465342
 File size of filesystems.docker is 1344 (1 block of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
 0:        0..       0:  348117738.. 348117738:      1:             last,shared,eof
 foo: 1 extent found
```

caveat: I'm not sure what happens if part of a file is altered so that only some blocks are in common.

caveat 2: I don't know if this works on btrfs (comment or edit if you do)