# Is there filesystem that allows me to insert some block in the middle of file in O(1)?

Tags: filesystems, system-programming

Assuming

- we have huge file *F*.
- we like to put "around" seek *s* a new empty (filled with zeros) block in O(1) time (i.e. without rewriting all remining part)
- "around" means we can round *s* to nearest filesystem blocksisze, and block to insert could be also filesystem blocksize

Is there a systemcall/filesystem that would allow such?

If not, is it good idea to mimic such behaviour using `btrfs_clone` (mentined [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131406/9689) ) and how?

Comment: If you only modify, you can use dd with seek, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17203140/3812704 . However, if you add a block, that will only work with xfs (linux >= 4.1) or ext4 (linux >= 4.2)as per other answer there http://stackoverflow.com/a/33339013/3812704

Comment: see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94041/119298) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339013/544721) :

> As of Linux 4.1, [fallocate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) supports the
>   `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE` flag, which allows one to insert a hole of a
>   given length in the middle of a file without rewriting the following
>   data. However, it is rather limited: the hole must be inserted at a
>   filesystem block boundary, and the size of the inserted hole must be a
>   multiple of the filesystem block size. Additionally, in 4.1, this
>   feature was only supported by the XFS filesystem, with Ext4 support
>   added in 4.2.

From [fallocate(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) :

```
fallocate -d [-o offset] [-l length] filename
(...)
       -d, --dig-holes
              Detect  and  dig  holes.   This  makes  the  file  sparse in-place, without using extra disk space.  The minimum size of the hole depends on
              filesystem I/O block size (usually 4096 bytes).  Also, when using this option, --keep-size is implied.  If no range is specified by --offset
              and --length, then the entire file is analyzed for holes.

              You  can  think  of  this option as doing a "cp --sparse" and then renaming the destination file to the original, without the need for extra
              disk space.

              See --punch-hole for a list of supported filesystems.
(...)
       -p, --punch-hole
(...)
              Supported for XFS (since Linux 2.6.38), ext4 (since Linux 3.0), Btrfs (since Linux 3.7) and tmpfs (since Linux 3.5).
```